# Command \multirow not working for tables

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to build a table like this:

[image]

But I'm having trouble at making the multirows. 
In order to build the line four of the table my attempt is:

`\hline \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{turn}{90}Senso de utilização \end{turn}} & 1 & Lâmpadas  & Iluminação & 4 &  &  &  \\`

But the result, from the whole code, is:

[image]

And the complete code it's shown below:

`\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{EQUIPE}: Bruno, Gustavo, Matheus, Leila e Pietro.}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Nota (1 a 5)}    \\ 
            \hline  \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Local}: Laboratório de Eficiência Energética.}   & Data 1 & Data 2  & Data 3  & Data 4  \\ 
            \hline 5S & Item  & Objeto  & Descrição  & 30/03/16 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{turn}{90}Senso de utilização \end{turn}} & 1 & Lâmpadas  & Iluminação & 4 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 2 & Capela  & Guarda vasilhas contendo ácido & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 3 & Grade & Isola do ambiente externo  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Utilizado para experimentação  & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 5 & Caixas & Sem utilização. Localização imprópria & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Posicionadas corretamente  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 2 & Capela & Desorganizada & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Desorganizada & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 5&  Caixas& Falta de identificação e responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Empoeiradas & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 2 & Capela & Muito suja por ácido  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 3 & Grade & Empoeirada & 4 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Empoeiradas & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 5 & Caixas & Empoeiradas e com teias de aranha & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 2 & Capela & Sem medidas para a padronização  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 3 & Grade & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 5&  Caixas& Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Falta de manutenção & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 2 & Capela & Falta de limpeza e de responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Falta de instruções de uso & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline  & 5 & Caixas & Falta de responsáveis  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{MÉDIA GERAL}}   &2.22  &  &  &  \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}%
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{#1}}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{EQUIPE}: Bruno, Gustavo, Matheus, Leila e Pietro.}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Nota (1 a 5)}    \\ 
\cline{1-8}  \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Local}: Laboratório de Eficiência Energética.}  & Data 1 & Data 2  & Data 3  & Data 4  \\ 
\cline{1-8} 5S & Item  & Objeto  & Descrição  & 30/03/16 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-8}   \multirowcell{-6}[-11.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.6em}\rot{\thead{Senso \\de\\ utilização}}}& 1 & Lâmpadas  & Iluminação & 4 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 2 & Capela  & Guarda vasilhas contendo ácido & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 3 & Grade & Isola do ambiente externo  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Utilizado para experimentação  & 3 &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-8}  & 5 & Caixas & Sem utilização. Localização imprópria & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  \multirowcell{-6}[-11.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.6em}\rot {\thead{Senso \\de\\ utilização}}} & 1 & Lâmpadas & Posicionadas corretamente  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
& 2 & Capela & Desorganizada & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Desorganizada & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-8}  & 5&  Caixas& Falta de identificação e responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  \multirowcell{-6}[-11.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.6em}\rot {\thead{Senso \\de\\ utilização}}} & 1 & Lâmpadas & Empoeiradas & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 2 & Capela & Muito suja por ácido  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 3 & Grade & Empoeirada & 4 &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-8}  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Empoeiradas & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-8}  & 5 & Caixas & Empoeiradas e com teias de aranha & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  \multirowcell{-6}[-11.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.6em}\rot {\thead{Senso \\de\\ utilização}}} & 1 & Lâmpadas & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 2 & Capela & Sem medidas para a padronização  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
 \cline{2-8}  & 3 & Grade & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-8}  & 5&  Caixas& Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  \multirowcell{-6}[-11.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.6em}\rot {\thead{Senso \\de\\ utilização}}} & 1 & Lâmpadas & Falta de manutenção & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 2 & Capela & Falta de limpeza e de responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{2-8}  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Falta de instruções de uso & 1 &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-8}  & 5 & Caixas & Falta de responsáveis  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-8} \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{MÉDIA GERAL}}   &2.22  &  &  &  \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}%
 }
\end{document}
```

[image: comli]

Comment: I like your solution, but the way the table is positioned is violing the right margin

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

using cline instead of hline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{EQUIPE}: Bruno, Gustavo, Matheus, Leila e Pietro.}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Nota (1 a 5)}    \\ 
    \hline  \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Local}: Laboratório de Eficiência Energética.}   & Data 1 & Data 2  & Data 3  & Data 4  \\ 
    \hline 5S & Item  & Objeto  & Descrição  & 30/03/16 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{turn}{90}Senso de utilização \end{turn}} & 1 & Lâmpadas  & Iluminação & 4 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 2 & Capela  & Guarda vasilhas contendo ácido & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 3 & Grade & Isola do ambiente externo  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Utilizado para experimentação  & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 5 & Caixas & Sem utilização. Localização imprópria & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 1 & Lâmpadas & Posicionadas corretamente  & 5 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    & 2 & Capela & Desorganizada & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}
    \hline  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Desorganizada & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 5&  Caixas& Falta de identificação e responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Empoeiradas & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 2 & Capela & Muito suja por ácido  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 3 & Grade & Empoeirada & 4 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Empoeiradas & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 5 & Caixas & Empoeiradas e com teias de aranha & 2 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 2 & Capela & Sem medidas para a padronização  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 3 & Grade & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 5&  Caixas& Sem medidas para a padronização & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 1 & Lâmpadas & Falta de manutenção & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 2 & Capela & Falta de limpeza e de responsáveis & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 3 & Grade & Não se aplica &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 4 & Bancadas de eletrotécnica & Falta de instruções de uso & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline  & 5 & Caixas & Falta de responsáveis  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{MÉDIA GERAL}}   &2.22  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]